# "Subscript out of range" error in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

The following code gives the error "subscript out of range":

```
Sub Workbooks2(str)
     Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & str)
     Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & str).Close ' <<<<< subscript out of range error
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works (removed the path to the file in the Close command):

```
Sub Workbooks2(str)
     Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & str)
     Workbooks(str).Close 
End Sub
```